# Pass by value to virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a question on pass-by-value object construction and virtual methods.

I have a virtual method like this:

```
typedef boost::function1<void, void*> Task

class ITaskPool
{
    //......

    virtual AddTask(Task task) = 0;
};
```

And then an implementation like

```
class TaskPool : public ITaskPool
{
    //......

    AddTask(Task task);
};
```

If I use it like this;

```
void MyFunc(void* arg)
{

}

int main()
{
    TaskPool tp;
    tp.AddTask(&MyFunc); 
}
```

Will a Task object be created twice, once for when it is passed to the virtual method, and another when it is passed to the method of the derived class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one copy would be created.
When you declare a function virtual, method of that derived class is called through dynamic binding. Its not the case that first method A is called and then method B is called.
COmpiler decides at run time which method to call.

[Polymorphism and Dynamic Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong (missing return types), but no, only one copy is involved. I think you got the wrong idea about polymorphism. It's not like the base class method is called first, and then gets forwarded to the derived class. `TaskPool::AddTask` is directly called through dynamic dispatch (if it's called polymorphically).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one method here: the one you declared as `virtual` in the base class. What you provide in the derived class is an implementation for the method. Therefore, only one method will be called. Being a virtual method, its implementation will be usually selected at runtime, but only one will ever be called.

Answer (score 0):

Only one copy will be created ...

Comment: Do explain the reasoning for your answer as well.